# WordPress 2021 Theme Nav menubar not covering the entire page width

Tags: css, wordpress

---

Hi, I am building a website on WordPress using the 2021 theme and stackable plugin. I have built everything but now the problem is the top navigation menu bar. I have written custom CSS code to make it sticky now the problem is that it's not covering the entire screen. here is the code I wrote.

```
#masthead{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
z-index: 150;
background:white;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

> The  CSS data type represents a percentage value. It is often used to define a size as relative to an element's parent object.

Consider the documentation of what `percentage`, `x%`, or `100%` (in your case) means in CSS. The width is relative to the parent container so if the parent container is not the full width of the viewport, then putting `width: 100%` will only fill that parent and not the entire viewport.

In your case, my first *guess* would be that the body has a margin as many browsers add in their browser stylesheet. If it's 8px 'indented' on each side, that's likely the case.

Here is a reduced reproduction: https://codepen.io/stevefrost/pen/XWMLZpW

Note how there is 8px space on the left and right which is attributed to the margin on the body added by the browser's stylesheet.

If this is not your case, please add a reduced reproduction and we can help further!

Answer (score 0):

Remove  width:100%;

Add

```
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 150;
    background: white;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 100%;
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi it's not working it put a bar in the center with spaces on both sides. Space has now shared on both sides.

Comment: Is it in local host ? If it's live you can share the link

Comment: I've Updated the CSS in answer please add that.......  max-width:100%; 
this will resolve the issue

Comment: Hey, let me know if that works. After adding max-width attribute